# JasperSoft - Formato de Data

Tags: rest, post, jasper, jaspersoft-studio, simpledateformat

Olá,

Temos a seguinte versão do JasperSoft:

```
<serverInfo>
   <build>BUILD_DATE_STAMP_BUILD_TIME_STAMP</build>
   <dateFormatPattern>yyyy-MM-dd</dateFormatPattern>
   <datetimeFormatPattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</datetimeFormatPattern>
   <edition>CE</edition>
   <version>6.1</version>
</serverInfo>
```

Acontece o seguinte:

> Quando geramos um relatorio pelo proprio
>   **localhost:8080/jasperserver/** e monitoro o trafego de dados, percebo que a data no input "20/05/2018" é convertida para
>   "2018-05-20" para ser mandada ao servidor. 
>   (Mudamos as configurações
>   de data do arquivo **jasperserver_config.properties**)

Porém, temos uma ERP que usamos para apontar determinados relatórios para os usuários poderem gerar. Mas, a ERP manda o comando via rest com o formato **dd/mm/yyyy**. Não temos como mudar o formato da ERP pois não temos acesso ao código fonte.

Minha duvida é: como mudar o formato de data aceito pelo servidor para "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Desde já agradeço.

Atenciosamente.

> **Edit:** Segue imagem para melhor entendimento do problema:
>   https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPu7N.jpg